# cannnot install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an Intel Quad Q9450@ 2.66GHzx4, 64 bit. I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.3. Afte downloading the iso file and clickimg it, a series of folders is saved, and there is no executable file or the like. I have also tried burning a dvd within ubuntu of the new os files by right clicking on the iso and burning ot to dvd, however, the dvd contains the same series of files and no executable, and no expanation text. I am new to ubuntu and the cumputer was given to me. How do inStall/upgrade? Thanks

Comment: why are you installing rather than upgrading ?

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from that DVD. Your other option will be putting the ISO image on a USB drive using this tool https://unetbootin.github.io/ then booting from the USB drive.

When you boot from either the DVD or USB drive, you will get various options regarding how to partition the space on your hard drive, keyboard settings ...etc